# How to modify a query to force use of an left prefix of an index?

Tags: mysql

I have SQL queries of the following kind:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE col2 >= x AND col2 < x+y
```

There is an index_1(col1, col2, col3) present on data_table whereas column one to three hold integer values greater than zero while null values aren't allowed. Since every left prefix of an index in MySQL is an index again my first approch was to modify the query in the hope that MySQL will use index_1 and the query speeds up. The modified query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE col2 >= x AND col2 < x+y OR col1 >0
```

My thought was when I add something that is always true but doesn't change the result MySQL would use the left prefix of index_1(col1, col2) but by a quick glance on EXPLAIN it unfortunately doesn't.

Does anyone know how to modify the query so that index_1 is used? Or is it just not possible?

For your information: data_table is really large and creating a new index with col2 is not an proper option due to the long creation time.

Comment: if it is always true shouldn't be there AND col1 > 0 ?

Comment: I think in this case it doesn't matter if I use the `AND` or `OR` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry that

i am answering so late i was reading about this before year and now i found the book which covers this and from that book, you should not use * because your index doesn't cover it, you should define columns precisely like SELECT col1,col2,col3 etc...or rewrite query to something like this:
`SELECT * FROM data_table JOIN (SELECT col1 FROM data_table WHERE col2>=x AND col2<x+y) AS table ON (table.col1=data_table.col1)`, here in subquery will be used index so it would be faster than your query...

Comment: Also I figuered out an different way your suggestion does work for me and it looks much more smarter. Anyway I'm going to check which performs better.

Answer (score 0):

`col1 > 0` is meaningless: it means "every row". Statistics used by the optimiser will show this, so the index is ignored or used inefficiently (scanned, not seeked)

Ideas:

- Why not create an index on col2 if that's what you use?
- Change the index to (col2, col1, col3)

Also, examine if you need the *current* index at all. Unless it's used for other queries, replace it with something more useful

Comment: Ok i got your point with col1 > 0 it was just something that came fast to my mind. Regarding your first idea: As I already stated thats not an proper option as long as there are other options. The creation will take several hours but I hardly can afford that. Regarding your second point: Doesn't that mean an `ALTER TABLE` with dropping the old index and adding the new one? Unfortunately I can't imagine that this will be much faster than the first idea. In addition the index_1 is used for other queries too.

Comment: Add another index, or accept things how they are... it is a binary choice